# how to convert a column to a new header in pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

I have a table that looks like this

```
    id  time_hour   val
0   1   2012-08-19  29
1   2   2012-08-19  26
```

I want to reindex the table by time but make the id as a new header to be like

```
              1      2
time_hour   val     val     
2012-08-19  206     206
```

how can I do this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```
df.pivot(index='time_hour', columns='id', values='val')
```